# ¿Como puedo rellenar este arrayList bidimensional de habitaciones con llaves, pero las llaves solo pueden estar en las habitaciones laterales?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, arraylist, array-bidimensional

Soy nuevo en el foro y no se bien como funciona, lo primero disculpas si no se entiende bien mi pregunta:

Estoy haciendo un juego en java que consiste en un personaje que tiene que escapar desde la parte mas alta de un edificio hasta la mas baja. El edificio es un arraylist bidimensional [5][3] de habitaciones que tiene: enemigos, armas, curaciones... y llaves.

Mi problema es que necesito que las llaves se coloquen de una manera especifica:

1. Solo puede haber una llave por piso
2. Las llaves solo pueden estar en las habitaciones de los laterales.
3. Las llaves tienen que colocarse de manera aleatoria en la habitación de la columna 0 o la 2

Actualmente he conseguido que cumpla todos los requisitos excepto el 3. No consigo que se coloquen las llaves de manera aleatoria, he probado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido... Actualmente lo que hago es rellenar todo el edificio con llaves e intentar eliminar luego una llave de cada piso pero al final siempre quedan pisos con llaves o algunos en los que borra todas.

También he intentado rellenarlas directamente solo con una llave por piso, pero al final termina siempre poniendome las llaves en las habitaciones de la columna 0.

os muestro mi parte del codigo que coloca las llaves:

```
public void rellenarHabitaciones(Habitacion[][] habitaciones, ArrayList<Arma> armas, ArrayList<Enemigo> enemigos, ArrayList<Curacion> curaciones, ArrayList<Llave> llaves, int numPisos) {
        int llavesEnFilaActual = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numPisos; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                boolean esCentral = (j == 1 && i != 0);
                Habitacion habitacion = new Habitacion(i, j, esCentral);
                habitaciones[i][j] = habitacion;
                if ((j == 0 || j == 2) && (i != 0 || j != 0)) {
                    Llave llaveHabitacion = llaves.remove(new Random().nextInt(llaves.size()));
                    habitacion.getListaLlavesHabitacion().add(llaveHabitacion);
                }

                Random random = new Random();
                int numeroAleatorio = random.nextInt(2);
                if (numeroAleatorio == 1) {

                    if (llaves.size() > 0 && llavesEnFilaActual == 0) {
                        habitacion.getListaLlavesHabitacion().clear();
                        llavesEnFilaActual++;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (llaves.size() > 0 && llavesEnFilaActual == 0) {
                        habitacion.getListaLlavesHabitacion().clear();
                        llavesEnFilaActual++;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Hola  JB-DEV, bienvenido, podrías aclararmnos algunas cosas?, por ejemplo, es un edificio de 5 pisos con tres habitaciones por piso?, cual es el criterio a la hora de colocar las armas, las curaciones y los enemigos?...  aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void rellenarHabitaciones( Habitacion[][] habitaciones, ArrayList <Arma> armas, 
                        ArrayList <Enemigo> enemigos, ArrayList <Curacion> curaciones, 
                        ArrayList <Llave> llaves, int numPisos ) {

     // recorremos los pisos
   for( int i = 0; i < numPisos; i++ ) {

        // recorremos e inicializamos las habitaciones del piso
      for( int j = 0; j < habitaciones[ 0 ].length; j++ ) {   

                                                 // puse cualquier cosa     
         habitaciones[ i ][ j ] = new Habitacion( 1 , 2, true );
      }

        // creamos una llave y la agregamos a lista
      Llave aux = new Llave();
      llaves.add( aux );

        // generamos aleatorio, si es mayor que 0.5, la llave va a pieza 0, sino a 2
      if( Math.random() > 0.5 ) {
         habitaciones[ i ][ 0 ].add( llaves.get( i ));  
      }
      else {
         habitaciones[ i ][ 2 ].add( llaves.get( i ));
      }         
   }     
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
   Edificio edie = new Edificio();
   Habitacion[][] habitaciones = new Habitacion[ 5 ][ 3 ]; 
   ArrayList <Arma> armas = new ArrayList<>(); 
   ArrayList <Enemigo> enemigos = new ArrayList<>(); 
   ArrayList <Curacion> curaciones = new ArrayList<>(); 
   ArrayList <Llave> llaves = new ArrayList<>(); 
   int numPisos = 5;
   edie.rellenarHabitaciones( habitaciones, armas, enemigos, curaciones, llaves, 5 );
}
```